# PL/SQL - usar variable for en select

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy tratando de imprimir una serie de caracteres especiales. Tengo el rango de bytes donde están esos caracteres. Este código forma parte de un código mayor, pero esta parte esta fallando.

```
DECLARE
  v_caracter NUMBER;
  v_cadena VARCHAR(100);
 BEGIN
 FOR v_caracter IN 33..37 LOOP
       Select CHR(v_caracter)
       into v_cadena
       from dual;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result: ' || v_cadena);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Cuando ejecuto el código, me sale en el log el mensaje `bloque anónimo terminado` pero no se ve en la consola ningún dato.

¿En que chorrada estoy metiendo la pata?

Comment: Antes de ejecutar ese bloque, en una instruccion independiente pon esto: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

Comment: Ves, y estas son las cosas que me hacen sentir muy tonto. Gracias. Ha sido poner el ´SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;´ antes del declare y funcionar.

Comment: @Valen, debieras publicar tu comentario como respuesta, de manera que quede oficialmente en el registro y pueda ser aceptada por el AP. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a tu problema es ejecutar el comando `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` para habilitar la salida en la consola de sqldeveloper